# Chrome App Store Manifest vs Web App Manifest

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-app, progressive-web-apps

I'm trying to publish my web app to the Chrome App store. I'm confused by [Step 2: Create a manifest file](https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/get_started_simple#step2) . Is this manifest file also a [Web App manifest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Manifest)?

If they are different, does it mean that i need to have two manifest.json files, if I intend to also make it a progressive web app while also listing on  Chrome App store? How should I go about doing this? Thanks.

Comment: Check this https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2014/11/Support-for-installable-web-apps-with-webapp-manifest-in-chrome-38-for-Android?hl=en

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is a different format, though they do share some common keys. (such as name, short_name)